# Best Way to Avoid Errors due to Settings/Configuration BEFORE Runtime

Tags: c#

A common problem is that programs may compile ok, but external (user/environment) settings may cause applications to crash during runtime.

Aside from performing checks all over the code, (alas actually performed during Runtime), 
I would like to have rule sets to assert **during build** that, at least default values settings, are coherent.

The simplest case may be, if default settings are hardcoded  :

```
Directory defaultDir = new Directory("D:\\Data");
UserLogin usr1 = "Jesse";
UserLogin usr2 = "James";
```

(yeah, "Booh"; this is an example, please **DO NOT** comment/answer on that unsignificant detail... I know it's hard for some of you, but please REFRAIN ! :-) )

So, is there a SIMPLE way to check DURING Build, that "D:\Data" exists, and that usr1 and usr2 do have different login strings etc...

I am sure there are assertion mechanisms in .Net, and maybe Unit Testing (I'd rather avoid the latter cause it may be oversized for the very light usage/need in this particular case. But I guess that's what Unit Tests are designed for too...)

Comment: A default setting that has the wrong value is *much* worse.  You won't get an exception, it just won't work right and it is not obvious why.  You'll waste a lot more time.

Comment: The problem is indeed that I would like to avoid having corrupted settings for some classes and realize it only during runtime

Answer (score 1):

In your project properties, you can set a command to run before the build, so you can create an exe that checks your settings, and run it in the "pre build event command line"

Comment: Ok. And what if Settings are not in setting but elsewhere in an XML file, or even sometimes hardcoded default values ?

Comment: your applications Settings can be wherever you want, your CheckSettingsConstraints.exe will do whatever you need : parse an xml file / c# file / read registry key, call web service.... (Although I strongly recommend you to avoid hard-coded values).